# Perl hash of arrays column name as keys

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to create a hash of arrays using the result of a sql query:
Eg.

Column1:

```
1                                         
2
3
4
```

Column2:

```
A 
B 
C 
D
```

Desired result:

```
my %by_col = (
    'Column1'=>['1','2','3','4'],
    'Column2'=>['A','B','C','D'],
);
```

I am able to get the result as array of hashes using:

```
while ($hash_ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    push @$hash_array_ref, { %$hash_ref };
}
```

But can't figure out the other way round.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
   for my $col_name (keys(%$row)) {
      push @{ $by_col{$col_name} }, $row->{$col_name};
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code definitely pointed me in the right direction, however, all values were coming out as "undef". I modified it a little and it seems to be working fine now.
foreach my $col_name (keys (%$row)) {
push @{ $hash_ref{$col_name} }, $row->{${col_name}};
}

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Indeed, oops! Fixed. (`$row->{$col_name}` would suffice)